# iOS app crashes while playing video

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When I play video containing audio with '`amr`' format in `iphone[version=8.3]`, the app quits immediately with this stacktrace:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported
>   orientations has no common orientation with the application, and
>   [_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning
>   YES' *** First throw call stack: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

How to handle this behaviour ?

Instead of exiting from the app, I need to inform the user with a message "`Unsupported audio format" or "video can't be played`".

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: `AVAsset` may help you to find out the format of individual tracks and/or play ability. but it's better to see the crash stacktrace for a true reason

Comment: STACK TRACE

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'
*** First throw call stack:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: that crash doesn't seem to be relevant to video/audio format. It's more like  about portrait/landscape orientation issue.

Comment: yea. I too think so.
Bcoz,the error is shown as :   
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'
What might be the reason behind this, how to resolve this issue ?????